# How could I dynamically(through PHP) assign sortable parameters instead of manually writing for each one?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

http://pastebin.ca/1996549

The pastebin link may help if my wording doesn't. I basically have a site that contains a bunch of custom sortables. Although the user can remove them no problem - they can never add them.

Any time a sortable needs to be added to the site I have to write up a set of identical parameters and the only thing that changes is the ID number (you can see the example in my pastebin).

How could I set this up as a loop instead of some 2000 line javascript file that contains X amount of identical blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could supply an array of the IDs necessary from the database with PHP and get an AJAX routine to bring this back as a JSON array, then iterate over that.

```
<?php
// boxIDList.php

// Connect to the DB
include("config.php");

$resultboxone = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM `activejobs` WHERE active = 1');

$boxIDList = array();       
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultboxone))  {
  $boxIDList[] = $row['id'];
}

echo json_encode($boxIDList);

exit();
?>
```

The jQuery could then be as follows: (I'm not sure how you use your routines)

```
$.getJSON('boxIDList.php', function(boxIDs) {
   $.each(boxIDs, function(i, value) {
     boxspank(value);
     boxspanklist(value);
   });
});
```

Comment: @Canadaland Soda - I'm happy to provide further explanation if required, let me know which bits confuse you and I'll elaborate.

Comment: Well, say that this is implemented. Inserting a new entry to active jobs (based on auto_increment) will tell the ridiculous amount of parameters (Two functions per) in my pastebin  to also apply to that entry. The problem is that I don't see where that's happening in your example. I see an array of active sortables being grabbed from my DB containing 'which' ID numbers to create sortables out of, but in your $getJSON statement I don't see what it's trying to accomplish(For each ID..do what?).

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to ask is that, by looking at the $.each {} section, what should I do with my parameters there? For boxspank I need to make an ajax call for content with a change to the URL from boxspank__IDNUMBER__.php to boxspank.php?id=(VALUE) so I can create one generic template page for the box that just uses the $_GET var to get that working properly. It also needs to apply some editable parameters. For Boxspanklist I need to make an Ajax call, set some sortable parameters and editable parameters....it all looks like I'm missing out on a key facet of your suggestion.

Comment: Well I mentioned in my answer that "I'm not sure how you use your routines", so I was not sure what you were planning on doing with them once received from PHP in the browser.  Your code appeared to have two functions, `boxspank()` and `boxspanklist()`, both seemed to be being called with the IDs to create the boxs, so I just put that down for reference.  The point is that inside the `$.each()` function, `value` is set to each of the boxIDs in turn, so you can create the boxs at that point.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, retardation (unfortunately) is roadblocking me from using your idea. http://pastebin.ca/2001214 shows what I am trying to do (But I'm positive the syntax is wrong). Maybe that makes things a bit less opaque for you to understand what I was trying to do.

Comment: Right, I made slight alterations to the layout: http://pastebin.ca/2001253 --- The problem seems to be a lack of awareness of the code flow, you are dealing with event-driven programming, asynchronously - if you need an order of code, you need to progress via the event callbacks.

Comment: To give some context, 'list' elements are the parent divs holding each sortable (They contain the labels/etc). The 'mylist' elements are the actual sortables. Thanks very much for your response. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Ah right, that makes more sense now.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Okay! Going to get started today and see if this works. Any reason you used cBoxID in the last three instances of it during the getJSON statement?

Comment: Everyone has there own variable naming conventions, I always prefix loop variables with 'c' meaning 'current', so that I know it is a variable that contains data or is bound to something specific to the current loop; I also do that within frequently used functions to denote the current pass.  The uses you mention are within a `.each()` loop.